# iOS click on push notification open concrete viewcontroller

Tags: ios, push-notification

Is it possible to open concrete **viewcontroller** when user tap on push notification?

I have news app, main view controller have a lot of news, and when user tap on some new I open next viewcontroller with description of this news.

When user tap push notification, how I can open second view controller?

I tried to send `Notification` to my `UINavigationController` and push two controllers, but it doesn't work fine, it open only first viewcontroller.

Comment: what is a concrete view controller?

Comment: Can I open any viewcontroller when user tap on push notification?

Comment: You can do whatever you want when the user taps on a push notification. In your app delegate you know if you have been launched via a tap on a push or via the app icon etc. and then you can display whatever view controller you want.

Comment: You can't push two view controllers at the same time if that is what you are trying to do, you can push one after the other, or you can switch from one stack of view controllers to a new stack. Your problem, whatever it is as you haven't described it clearly or shown any code, is nothing to do with tapping on a notification.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Swift Navigate to certain ViewController programmatically from push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43058261/ios-swift-navigate-to-certain-viewcontroller-programmatically-from-push-notifica)

Answer (score 2):

you can handle your app, when you tap a local or push notification, implementing the `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` or `application: didReceiveRemoteNotification:` method in your AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

}
```

If your app it's closed (not in background) you can verify if you received a notification in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    NSDictionary *userInfo = [launchOptions objectForKey: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if ( userInfo != nil )
        [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo];
}
```

I don't know how you are handling your news but you can post a notification to your main view controller informing that you have receive a notification, passing the "id" or the info of your new and then create your second view controller (you will need to verify if your `MainViewController` is already created in the stack of your `NavigationController`):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"IHaveReceivedANotification" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];

}
```