# iOS Swift Navigate to certain ViewController programmatically from push notification

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate

I use push notifications to inform the user about different types of events happening in the app. A certain type of push notification should open a special viewcontroller (f.e a notification about a new chat message does navigate to the chat on click)

To achieve this, i tried the following code inside my app delegate:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
 if var topController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
        while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
            topController = presentedViewController
        }
        topController.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 3
    }
}
```

It does not move anywhere. What am I missing here?

Comment: So you have a tabbar here and you want it go to tab#4 every time app become active?

Comment: the didbecomeactive is chosen for testing it out, but yes i have a tabbar controller and yes to tab #4 is correct too

Comment: Change your rootViewController to tab bar controller and you'll be ok

Comment: probably add `as! UITabbarViewController` for topController will work

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a simple class to navigate to any view controller in the view hierarchy from anywhere in one line of code by just passing the class type, so the code you'll write will be also decoupled from the view hierarchy itself, for instance:

```
Navigator.find(MyViewController.self)?.doSomethingSync()
Navigator.navigate(to: MyViewController.self)?.doSomethingSync()
```

..or you can execute methods asynchronously on the main thread also:

```
Navigator.navigate(to: MyViewController.self) { (MyViewControllerContainer, MyViewControllerInstance) in
    MyViewControllerInstance?.doSomethingAsync()
}
```

Here's the GitHub project link: https://github.com/oblq/Navigator

Comment: where to write this code ? because i am getting error the Value of type 'NotificationVC' has no member 'doSomethingSync' where NotificationVC is my viewcontroller

Comment: @roshanposakya 'doSomethingSync' is an invented func, set a real func of your 'NotificationVC'. Navigator.find or Navigator.navigate returns the instance of your VC, so, Navigator.find(NotificationVC.self) is exactly like calling NotificationVC()... so, after Navigator.find(NotificationVC.self)?. you can call any NotificationVC func or var.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need.
Use your navigation controller to push your notification view controller

```
    let mainStoryBoard : UIStoryboard       = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let navigationController : UINavigationController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainNavigationController") as! UINavigationController

    let notifcontrol : UIViewController     = (mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NotificationViewController") as? NotificationViewController)!

    navigationController.pushViewController(notifcontrol, animated: true)

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Answer (score 0):

The topController was already my TabBarController in this case!