# Load specific View after push notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to open the (Detail view) when I open the application from push notifications, I tried to find the answer but I could not.

I attached the image that shows the View I need to open (green view). Please guide me.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Swift Navigate to certain ViewController programmatically from push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43058261/ios-swift-navigate-to-certain-viewcontroller-programmatically-from-push-notifica)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below approch:

Add this method in the AppDelegate Class:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
   // Open Your Details view controller directly using segue
   // You can pass details id and then fetch details and display in the view.
    SettingViewController *moreVC = [[SettingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigationRootController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:moreVC];
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] presentViewController:navigationRootController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

This is another approch:

```
  - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

       // Register the below observer in the rootviewcontroller so its registered first and than Pass NSDictionary 
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"pushModalPopUp" object:userInfo];
    }
```

Comment: I am using objective c

Answer (score 0):

Window.rootView > A > B > C

This is a simple approach:

1. When you receive notification, add a key to NSUserDefault (e.g: "NeedShowViewC" = true), then load view controller A
2. In A view controller's viewDidLoad, check for that key ("NeedShowViewC"), if it is true, load view B, and so on.
3. When you finish showing view controller C, set that key back to false or remote it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note on Code Hunterr's 1st approach: 
Initiating a new viewcontorller (your target "green" VC) + new UINavigationVC:

```
SettingViewController *moreVC = [[SettingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationRootController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:moreVC];
```

These will create new instances of those two VCs. Although this might not be a problem functionally for you, it could potentially create a memory management issue. If a user is already viewing the green details view when they close the app, then receive a push, and as a result open the app and you auto-navigate them to the green VC again you'll have 2 instances of the green VC in memory (you can check the Xcode debugger memory map to see this in practice). If you do this again and again and the ARC doesn't release the previous instances of the VCs (depends on your MVC implementation), you might end up bloating your memory usage.

Also, displaying the details VC directly without the table view before will mess up your 'backwards' navigation as the new NavVC you just created wouldn't have the table view in its VC stack.

The alternative is:

1) Get the push notification using either didReceiveRemoteNotification() or the new (in iOS 10) [UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate)

2)  Using the app's root view controller, grab the navigation controller of your first tab -> the one that leads to your green details view.

3) Then roll back your navigation stack-> this will make sure that no matter what VC/view the user was last open on, your starting the navigation from scratch and de-allocating the details VCs (or any future VCs your add that are deeper than the tableVC) before allocating a new one.

4) Then tell the tableVC, which is the rootVC of the navVC you just grabbed to show the details of the row you need. You can do this by adding a public func/API to the tabelVC or use a notification that the tableVC observes (as suggested in Code Hunterr's 2nd approach).

Example (its in swift but it should be easy to translate to ObjC):

```
//grab the navVC - in this example I'm assuming your tabVC is the rootVC of the app you need the 1st VC of the tabVC's array
if let topNavController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.viewControllers.first as? UINavigationController {
            //grab the content VC (which is your table VC)
            if let topContentController = topNavController.viewControllers.first as? MyAppsTableView {
                //pop the navVC stack all the way back to its root (the table)
                topNavController.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
                //tell your table view to show detail of a certain row
                topContentController.pleaseShowItem(item: xyzzy)
            }
        }
```